# Get string after and before a special Characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following string and from that string I want all the data between DDD= and %

```
2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401
```

I have tried to get use following code but unable to get the desired output

```
my_string="2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401"
print(my_string.split("DDD=",1)[1])
```

Getting following output

```
1.08% XXX=2401
```

But I am looking output as

```
either 1.08 or 1.08%
```

Please help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401"
m = re.search(r"DDD=(.*?)%", s)  #if you want it to be strict and get only ints use r"DDD=(\d+\.?\d*)%"
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
1.08
```

Comment: Thanks it is working properly and getting expected output

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option which uses `split` twice rather than regex. It's not terribly flexible though and can easily break if the input format changes slightly. You can decide which option is best for your use case.

```
s = "2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401"
print(s.split('DDD=')[1].split('%')[0])
```

Results:

```
'1.08'
```

Depending on what you plan to do with the number, you might also want to cast it to a numeric type:

```
print(float(s.split('DDD=')[1].split('%')[0]))
```

Results:

```
1.08
```

Answer (score 0):

To match *all the data between DDD= and %*:

```
import re

test_str = "2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401"
m = re.search(r"DDD=([^%]+)%", test_str)
ddd = m.group(1) if m else m
print(ddd)    # 1.08
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string find operation:

**Example**

```
my_string="2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401"
fst = my_string.find("DDD=")
snd = my_string.find("%")
if fst >= 0 and snd >= 0
    print(my_string[fst+4,snd])
```

**Output**

```
1.08
```

Or you can use split:

**Example**

```
my_string="2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401"
(fst,snd) = my_string.split("DDD=");
(trd,fourth) = snd.split("%");
print(trd)
```

**Output**

```
1.08
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    my_string="2019-07-25 15:23:13 [Thread-0] DEBUG  - Serial : INFO: 
    QQQ=00000D00001111 AAA=8 BBB=0 CCC=0 DDD=1.08% XXX=2401"
    output1 = print(my_string.split("DDD=")[1][:5])
    #output1  =1.08%
    #output2 = print(my_string.split("DDD=")[1][:4])
    #output2  =1.08
```